# Simplicial homology of subdivision of a simplex is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've started learning a bit about simplicial homology, recently. On the way to proving topological invariance, the book (*'Elements of Algebraic Topology'*, Munkres) uses subdivisions and simplicial approximation. However the following simple statement is taken for granted in a proof, and I haven't been able to rigorously prove it myself. Namely

> If $K$ is any finite subdivision of $\Delta^n$, where $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-dimensional simplex, then the reduced homology $\tilde H_p(K)$ of $K$ vanishes identically.

This is used in the proof of the existence of the subdivision operator (***Theorem 17.2***, on page 96 of my edition). I think it might be relatively easy to see... but I'm at a loss, nevertheless.

At this point in the book, the reduced homology of a simplex and its boundary have been computed. So the above is known to be true for $K=\Delta^n$. More generally, it has been proven that a cone always has trivial homology (if that's of any help). No other homology theory (like singular homology) has been introduced, yet.

I'd very much appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: In the version of the book I'm looking at, your statement is not assumed, and is indeed a consequence of Theorem 17.2. The proof is long, could you say a bit more about where and how this statement is used?

Comment: @JustinYoung: Yes, I will gladly do so! I have a paperback edition. The statement is in part 1 of the proof. The point I'm confused about is below figure 17.1 in my edition, where it is written "[...] We define $$\Theta(\tau) = K(\sigma_\tau),$$ $$\Phi(\tau) = K'(\sigma_\tau);$$ both complexes are acyclic. [...]" Here $\sigma_\tau$ is a simplex of the complex $K$, $K'$ is a subdivision of $K$ and $K'(\sigma_\tau)$ denotes the complex which is the union of all simplices of $K'$ which lie in $\sigma_\tau$. I don't see how to go about proving that $K'(\sigma_\tau)$ is acyclic.

Comment: Ah, well, $\sigma_\tau$ is a simplex in $K$, so $K(\sigma_\tau)$ is just that simplex and its faces, therefore acyclic. As for $K'(\sigma_\tau)$, that is acyclic by the standing assumption of part 1: namely, that for any simplex $\sigma$ of $K$, the induced subdivision $K'(\sigma)$ of $\sigma$ is acyclic.

Comment: @JustinYoung: Ah, damn. :) Looks like I had already forgotten this standing assumption when I came to this part of the proof. Thank you very much for pointing it out. If you'd like to copy your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it!

Comment: @SamL. Is this used on the way to prove Excision?

Comment: @BenjaLim: The excision theorem has already been proved in an earlier chapter. The subdivision operator constructed in the present theorem is later used to show topological invariance of simplicial homology groups of the polytope of a simplicial complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, $K'(\sigma_\tau)$ is acyclic by the standing assumption of part 1: namely, that for any simplex $\sigma$ of K, the induced subdivision $K'(\sigma)$ of $\sigma$ is acyclic.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth pointing out that the question above is answered in *part 4* of the same proof given in Munkres' book.

**Sketch:** Let $L = \Delta^n$ and suppose we are give a subdivision $L'$ of $L$. Let $g: L' \to L$ be a simplicial approximation to the identity on $L$.

By successive barycentric subdivision of $L$, we can find a simplicial approximation $f: \operatorname{sd}^N L \to L'$ to the identitiy on $L'$ and then, by successive barycentric subdivision of $L'$, we also find a simplicial approximation $k: \operatorname{sd}^M L' \to \operatorname{sd}^N L$ to the identity on $\operatorname{sd}^N L$. This gives us a sequence of maps

$$\operatorname{sd}^M L' \overset k\longrightarrow \operatorname{sd}^N L \overset f\longrightarrow L' \overset g\longrightarrow L$$

where $f\circ k: \operatorname{sd}^M L'\to L'$ and $g\circ f: \operatorname{sd}^N L\to L$ are simplicial approximations to the identity. Now using that a cone has trivial homology, we can see that the homology of the *barycentric subdivision* of a complex is the same as that of the complex. (indeed we can find an explicit subdivision operator in this case$

But then $f_\ast\circ h_\ast = 1_\ast$ and $g_\ast \circ f_\ast = 1_\ast$ implies that $f_\ast$ is an isomorphism, hence $$\tilde H_p(L') = \tilde H_p(\operatorname{sd}^N L) = \tilde H_p(L) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If  ${dim}\left({\sigma}\right)$ is greater than $ p$, then any $p-$ cycle of ${sd^n}\left({\sigma}\right)$ can be pushed off the simplices not in ${sd}\left({\sigma}\right)$ by subtracting a suitable p-boundary ,the trick munkres uses in sec. 5 of this book.Then as ${sd}\left({\sigma}\right)$ is acyclic being a cone we're done.If ${dim}\left({\sigma}\right)$ = $p$,then for any $p-$ cycle $c$, the boundary , $\partial{c}$= $0$, so c must be equal on all simplices and hence a multiple of $\sum_{i}{\tau}_{i}$ ( where $\tau_{i}$ ranges over all $p$ -simplices of $\sigma$) ,but then since it is $0$ on $Bd(\sigma)$ it must be $0$ all over. So , ${sd^n}\left({\sigma}\right)$ is acyclic.

Comment: "Now using that a cone has trivial homology, we can see that the homology of the barycentric subdivision of a complex is the same as that of the complex" in Sam's answer is vague .